# ES6 promise settled callback?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-promise

I want to run the same action whether my Promise resolved successfully or not. I don't want to bind the same function to both args of `.then`. Isn't there a `.always` like jQuery has? If not, how do I achieve this?

Comment: can't you do .finally(function(){...})?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26667598/will-javascript-es6-promise-support-done-api

Comment: @CharlieWynn It's undefined in Babel and not listed on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/catch).

Comment: You can try the `when` package https://www.npmjs.com/package/when

Answer (score 37, accepted):

> Isn't there a `.always` like jQuery has?

<s>No, [there's not (yet)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27285199/1048572). Though there is an [active proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-promise-finally), so maybe ES2018.</s>
Yes, there is: [promise `.finally()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/finally) is part of the standard since ES2018.

> If not, how do I achieve this?

You can implement the `finally` method yourself like this:

```
Promise.prototype.finally = function(cb) {
    const res = () => this
    const fin = () => Promise.resolve(cb()).then(res)
    return this.then(fin, fin);
};
```

or more extensively, with passing resolution information to the callback:

```
Promise.prototype.finally = function(cb) {
    const res = () => this
    return this.then(value =>
        Promise.resolve(cb({state:"fulfilled", value})).then(res)
    , reason =>
        Promise.resolve(cb({state:"rejected", reason})).then(res)
    );
};
```

Both ensure that the original resolution is sustained (when there is no exception in the callback) and that promises are awaited.

Comment: I think error callback of the `this.then` in pollyfill should throw rather then return.

Comment: @dfsq: It does by returning the original, rejected promise :-)

Comment: You are right, `this` is original promise because of `=>`, sure.

Comment: Your first example has the same problem as [described here](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#finallyfunction-handler---promise) doesn't it? I'm not sure about your "more extensive" solution though.

Comment: @Mark: you mean that exceptions are swallowed? No, it does not, as I explained to dfsq :-) There is however a difference to the `finally` keyword, as you can `return` from a `finally { }` block but not from the promise `.finally` callback.

Comment: Rejecting is not the same as throwing. My understanding is `finally` should throw outside of the promise chain. E.g. `.catch(e => setTimeout(() => { throw e; }))`.

Comment: @jib: rejecting is exactly the same in the context of promises. No, `finally` should not throw the exceptions outside of the promise chain, that's what `.done()` did, which is deprecated in favour of unhandled rejection detection.

Comment: Your first implementation (without the values) does appear to be in-line with [the spec](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-promise-finally), so that's good :-)

Comment: @riv No, that's a [shorthand notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34414766/javascript-object-literal-what-exactly-is-a-b-c).

Answer (score 10):

With async/await, you can a combination of `await` with `try/finally`, like so:

```
async function(somePromise) {
  try {
    await somePromise();
  } finally {
    // always run this-- even if `somePromise` threw something
  }
}
```

Here's a real example I have running in production with Node, using Babel's [async-to-generator](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-async-to-generator/) plugin.

```
// Wrap promisified function in a transaction block
export function transaction(func) {
  return db.sequelize.transaction().then(async t => {
    Sequelize.cls.set('transaction', t);
    try {
      await func();

    } finally {
      await t.rollback();
    }
  });
}
```

I use this code inside a mocha test alongside the [Sequelize ORM](http://sequelizejs.com/) to start a DB transaction, and regardless of the outcome of the DB calls within the test, always roll back at the end.

This is roughly analogous to Bluebird's `.finally()` method, but IMO, far nicer syntax!

(**Note**: In case you're wondering why I'm not `await`ing on the first Promise- it's an implementation detail of Sequelize. It uses [CLS](https://www.npmjs.com/package/continuation-local-storage) to 'bind' a SQL transaction to a Promise chain. Anything that incurs *inside* the same chain is scoped to the transaction. Anything outside isn't. Therefore, awaiting on the Promise would have 'closed' the transaction block and broken the chain. I threw this example in to show you how 'vanilla' Promise handling can be mixed alongside async functions, and play well together.)

Comment: Why aren't you using `async function transaction` and drop that `then` call as well?

Comment: Neat! Never thought about using `try/finally` with `async/await`. That'll come in handy.

Comment: @Bergi - Sequelize uses something called 'CLS' to scope a transaction block to a Promise chain. If I used `await`, it would return a transaction handler but subsequent SQL would be _outside_ of the block, and therefore not scoped to the transaction. It's an implementation detail of Sequelize.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't/can't update the prototype, the way to hack a finally is:

```
executeMyPromise()
.then(function(res){ return {res: res}; })
.catch(function(err){ return {err: err}; })
.then(function(data) {
    // do finally stuff
    if (data.err) {
        throw data.err;
    }
    return data.res;
}).catch(function(err) {
    // handle error
});
```

Comment: I don't think that's the same. See the [3rd and 4th points here](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-promise-finally#why-not-thenf-f). We can actually use Bergi's solution without modifying the prototype. You just have to call it funny: `finallyFunc.call(thePromise, callback)`. Works well with the bind operator.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my implementation of .finally().

```
Promise.prototype.finally = function(cb) {
   return this.then(v=>Promise.resolve(cb(v)),
                    v=>Promise.reject(cb(v)));
};
```

I tested it:

```
(new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{resolve(5);})).finally(x=>console.log(x));  //5

(new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{reject(6);})).finally(x=>console.log(x));  //6

(new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{reject(7);}))
.then(x=>x,y=>y)
.catch(x=>{throw "error";}) 
.finally(x=>{console.log(x); throw "error"; return x;})  // 7
.then(x=>console.log(x),y=>console.log('e'));  //e
// Uncaught (in promise) undefined
```

Answer (score 1):

### Summary:

We now also have access to `Promise.prototype.finally()`. This is a function which can be put on the promise chain as a last element to perform some cleanup. it works the following way when compared to `Promise.then` and `Promise.catch`:

- `Promise.then` **only** gets called when the promise is resolved (if you only put it the first argument callback function)
- `Promise.catch` **only** gets called when the promise is rejected
- `Promise.finally` **always** gets called when a promise is fullfilled, so both when the promise gets rejected or resolved.

### Example:

```js
let Prom = new Promise((res, rej) => {
  let random = Math.random();
  
  if (random > 0.5) {
    res(1);
  } else {
    rej('Error occured')
  }

  
});


Prom.then((val) => {
  console.log(val);
  return val * 10;
}).catch((err) => {
  console.log(err);
}).finally(() => {
  console.log('finally executed');
})
```

In the above exapmle we can observe that `finally` is always executed regardless if the promise resolves or rejects. Not that `finally` should ideally always be at the end of the promise chain to do some cleanup which should be executed regardless of Promise outcome.

The advantage of using `finally` is that it avoids the need for code duplication because it is executed for both a resolved and a rejected promise. Otherwise we would have to use hacks like:

```
.then(onfullfilled, onfullfilled)
```

or

```
.then(onfullfilled)
.catch(onfullfilled)
```

Note that now we have to define the `onfullfilled` function as a named function outside the promisehandler itself (or pass in 2 anonymous function copies which is even less elegant). `Promise.finally` solves this problem for us.

Answer (score 0):

No need to introduce new concepts

```
const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  /*some code here*/
});

promise.then(() => {
  /* execute success code */
}, () => {
  /* execute failure code here */
}).then(() => {}, () => {}).then(() => {
  /* finally code here */
});
```

Comment: That would cause the return value from the first .then() branch to be discarded, wouldn't it?

Answer (score 0):

To extend **[Bergi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32362233/4822948)** answer.

Returning Promise.reject() in catch handler will prevent finnalizing 'then' to be called.

So if you going to handle promise error 2+ times you should use boilerplate like this:

```
return myPromise()
.then(() => ... )
.catch((error) => {
  ...
  myFinnaly();
  return Promise.reject(error);
})
.then(() => myFinnaly());
```

Answer (score 0):

allSettled works directly as finally:

```js
Promise.allSettled([promiseSuccess, promiseReject])
  .then(results => console.log);
```

Check: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/allSettled