# why do not throw syntax error at local environment?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, syntax-error, jshint

I'm using nodejs, express.

My code was...

```
var option = { name: 'Tobi' };
app.render('email', { option });
```

and I deployed to **production** env.
it threw error `SyntaxError: Unexpected token }`

and my lovely node server died... :scream:

anyway, I fixed it. like this...

```
var option = { name: 'Tobi' };
app.render('email', option);
```

***Buuuuut,***

in my **local** env, I couldn't catch that.
I know it was my mistake.

**How can I catch the syntax error in local environment?**

I thought it can be done by jshint.
but i couldn't find the appropriate option from jshint.

I need your help. THX

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The `{ option }` syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34414766/javascript-object-literal-what-exactly-is-a-b-c) is new in ES6.

Presumably the problem is that your development environment is using a newer version of NodeJS than your production environment so that your production environment does not support the new syntax. (Support was added in [version 4 of NodeJS](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#test-object_literal_extensions_shorthand_properties)).

Make sure that you match software versions between your production and development environments.