# I am trying to export this JSON data for importing in the project however it shows unexpected syntax error

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, native-base

When it was in the same file as component worked perfectly. Now I am trying to exclude it from component to make project cleaner. However it shows unexpected syntax errors. File format is JSON. How can this code be fixed and work as it needs to be?

```
const postsData = [

      {
        id: 1,
        title: "How to start a business with 100$",
        published: "14h ago",
        image: require("../img/img1.jpg"),
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        title: "Get funding for your startup",
        published: "19h ago",
        image: require("../img/img2.jpg"),
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        title: "Latest Fashion Trends for 2018",
        published: "14h ago",
        image: require("../img/img3.jpg"),
      },

    ]

    export {postsData};
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
export default [
      {
        id: 1,
        title: "How to start a business with 100$",
        published: "14h ago",
        image: require("../img/img1.jpg"),
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        title: "Get funding for your startup",
        published: "19h ago",
        image: require("../img/img2.jpg"),
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        title: "Latest Fashion Trends for 2018",
        published: "14h ago",
        image: require("../img/img3.jpg"),
      }
    ]
```

and `import` it like

`import postsData from 'filepath';`

**PS**:

- there is no naming convention for `postsData` you can name it
  anything.
- your `json` file should have an extension `.js` for your case because you're not using `JSON objects`

Comment: You wrote export default [.... How it knows if its a postsData? in your example it's not defined.

Comment: You can name it anything.

Comment: there is no need to define any name in your `JSON` file. You have to name it when using `import`

Comment: syntax error shows inside this file  on the fist line : export default [

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162582/discussion-between-ahsan-ali-and-artur).

Comment: change your `.json` file to `.js`

Comment: @VedPrakash it will also work without `""` in this case, if following my sequence.

Comment: @AhsanAli i am getting bellow      isue "Error: Parse error on line 1:
[{  id: 1,  title: "How
----^
Expecting 'STRING', '}', got 'undefined' "

Comment: @AhsanAli : please use json lint to validate json-  [json lint](https://jsonlint.com/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add double "" mark
like this below

```
{
"id": "1",
"title": "How to start a business with 100$",
"published": "14h ago",
}
```

please use json lint to validate json-  [json lint](https://jsonlint.com/)

please follow

```
[{
        "id": "1",
        "title": "How to start a business with 100$",
        "published": "14h ago",
        "images": [{
                    "bannerImg1": "./images/effy.jpg"
                },
                {
                    "id": "2",
                    "title": "Get funding for your startup",
                    "published": "19h ago",
                    "images": [{
                            "bannerImg1": "./images/effy.jpg"
                        },
                        {
                            "id": "3",
                            "title": "Latest Fashion Trends for 2018",
                            "published": "14h ago",
                            "images": [{
                                "bannerImg1": "./images/effy.jpg"
                            }]

                        }
                    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is a **JSON** file like **MyFile.json**, then you cant export any thing from JSON file with your current code as it contains keywords like **export** or **const** and you cant use JavaScript **keywords** in JSON file.

You can change the extension of the file to **MyFile.js**

OR

You can create a json file like **MyFile.json** and put only JSON code

```
{
"id": "1",
"title": "How to start a business with 100$",
"published": "14h ago",
}
```

and require it from JS file like : 
`import data from './MyFile.json'`

Answer (score 0):

This is not a JSON, it's just a javascript file (according to syntax).
The last line constructs object with [shorthand property](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34414791/3344612) and [exports](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export) it in the form `export { name1, name2, …, nameN };` where `name1`, `name2`, ..., `nameN` are *named* properties.
To [import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) named property use following syntax:

```
import { export } from "module-name";
```

In your case it would be

```
import { postsData } from "<your file without js ext>"
```

Answer (score 0):

As said above,this is not a JSON but just a Object.

First,New a js file,you can name this file whatever you want.for example,`data.js`

Then write like this in `data.js`:

```
export defult{
  postsData: [
      {
        id: 1,
        title: "How to start a business with 100$",
        published: "14h ago",
        image: require("../img/img1.jpg"),
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        title: "Get funding for your startup",
        published: "19h ago",
        image: require("../img/img2.jpg"),
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        title: "Latest Fashion Trends for 2018",
        published: "14h ago",
        image: require("../img/img3.jpg"),
      },
   ]
}
```

Finally,in your component file:

```
import {xxxx} from './data';
```

in this way,you can get your data,`xxxx.postsData`.

Answer (score 0):

```
with commonjs module
const express = require("express");
const config = require("./config.json");

typescript

{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2015",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "strict": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true
  }
}

import law from './keywords/law.json'
import special from './keywords/special.json'
```

Answer (score -1):

If you have .JSON file and everything inside it is json then you need not export it like normal module. You simply import it in other module and use it like normal object. Thats it !