# how to display objects in an array with spacebars

Tags: meteor, spacebars

This may be a duplicate question but I've yet to find a solution to my specific problem. I have a db set up like this:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5c43b0e463ad7e8adfa4f07a"), "name" : "The Box", "price" : "80", "parts" : [ { "pname" : "piccolo", "pprice" : "3" }, { "pname" : "Flute 1", "pprice" : "3" } ] }
```

Is there a way to iterate through the parts array and do a nested {{#each}} loop so that I can display the name of each document and each part within the name? my code so far:

```
<tbody>
                    {{#each pieces}}
                    <tr class="itemList">
                        <td class="name">{{name}}</td>
                        <td class="pdf">PDF</td>
                        <td class="audio">AUDIO</td>
                        <td class="format">FORMAT</td>
                        <td class="price" >${{price}}</td>
                        <td><input class ="qty" type ="number" name ="quantity" value="0"></td>
                    </tr>
                    {{#each parts}}
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="3"></td>
                        <td class="partName">{{pname}}</td>
                        <td class="partPrice">{{pprice}}</td>
                        <td><input class="partQty" type="number" name="quantity" value="0"></td>
                    </tr>
                    {{/each}}
                    {{/each}}
                </tbody>
```

and my helpers:

```
   Template.band.helpers({
pieces: function(){
    return bandmusic.find({})
},
parts: function(){
    return bandmusic.find({parts})
} })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing to realise is that your `parts` helper a) doesn't work and b) isn't what you need anyway.

- a) `bandmusic.find({parts})` doesn't mean "return the parts array from documents in the bandmusic collection", which is what you seem to be wanting it to do.

`{parts}` is ES6 shorthand for `{parts: parts}` (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34414766/javascript-object-literal-what-exactly-is-a-b-c)). But your function has no variable `parts` - so in your `find`, what you're really saying is "find documents which match the condition `{parts: undefined}`

- b) But that doesn't matter, because you don't need a helper here in the first place.

What you're trying to do with your nested `#each` is loop through each *document* in the database, and then within each *document*, loop through the `parts` array.

Well, you get the *documents* from your `pieces` helper, and each document contains a `parts` array, which you can just loop through without needing a helper.

- c) Simple solution

Your code should work if you just delete the `parts` helper. Blaze has a lookup order which you can read about [here](http://blazejs.org/guide/understanding-blaze.html#Lookup-order). What this means is that when Blaze sees `parts`, it first thinks "is there a helper called `parts`?" - which there is, and it's not working, so nothing happens.

But what you want it to think is "Is there a field in the current data context called `parts`" - which there is, but `helpers` come higher in the lookup order so it never gets there.

So the simplest solution in theory is to remove the helper.

- d) Clearer solution and best practice

As you can see from the `lookup order` link, it's often unclear what refers to what in Spacebars/Blaze. You can make things much clearer by using the syntax described in the [Blaze docs for `each`](http://blazejs.org/api/spacebars.html#Each)

Instead of `#each array` you should introduce a new variable to refer to the current item in the array - `#each item in array`. And then access the item's properties as usual - `item.prop1 - item.prop2`

So your new code becomes:

```
{{#each piece in pieces}}
  <tr class="itemList">
    <td class="name">{{piece.name}}</td>
    <td class="pdf">PDF</td>
    <td class="audio">AUDIO</td>
    <td class="format">FORMAT</td>
    <td class="price" >${{piece.price}}</td>
    <td><input class ="qty" type ="number" name ="quantity" value="0"></td>
  </tr>
  {{#each part in piece.parts}}
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3"></td>
      <td class="partName">{{part.pname}}</td>
      <td class="partPrice">{{part.pprice}}</td>
      <td><input class="partQty" type="number" name="quantity" value="0"></td>
    </tr>
  {{/each}}
{{/each}}
```

Comment: that makes a lot more sense. the each in context works a lot better and as soon as I altered my code it worked like a charm! Thank you for the clear explanation.

Comment: So then could I do an {{#if}} conditional to check if that array exists? so lets say some of the documents in the db have a parts array and others don't. So would that be {{#if piece.parts}} execute the other {{#each..in}} loop?

Comment: Yes, but much easier is {{#each...}}Some stuff {{else}} No Stuff Found {{/each}} - http://blazejs.org/api/spacebars.html#Each

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to create two helpers. Just using your first helper is working:

```
Template.hello.helpers({
  pieces() {
    let data = [{
      "_id": "5c43b0e463ad7e8adfa4f07a",
      "name": "The Box",
      "price": "80",
      "parts": [
        { "pname": "piccolo", "pprice": "3" },
        { "pname": "Flute 1", "pprice": "3" }
      ]
    }]

    return data;
  }
});
```

Then you can iterate on the pieces and on the parts. If you want to access inside your nested #each the piece name AND the part name. You can use `{{../name}}` to access the parent Datacontext.

```
<table class="table">
  <tbody>
    {{#each pieces}}
    <tr class="itemList">
      <td class="name">{{name}}</td>
      <td class="pdf">PDF</td>
      <td class="audio">AUDIO</td>
      <td class="format">FORMAT</td>
      <td class="price">${{price}}</td>
      <td><input class="qty" type="number" name="quantity" value="0"></td>
    </tr>
      {{#each parts}}
      <tr>
        <td colspan="3">{{../name}}</td>
        <td class="partName">{{pname}}</td>
        <td class="partPrice">{{pprice}}</td>
        <td><input class="partQty" type="number" name="quantity" value="0"></td>
      </tr>
      {{/each}}
    {{/each}}
  </tbody>
</table>
```

But using the `{{#each}}` block is not a good practice, **you should use `{{#each in}}`**.
The `{{#each in}}` block create a variable that you can use easily.

```
<table class="table">
  <tbody>
    {{#each piece in pieces}}
    <tr class="itemList">
      <td class="name">{{piece.name}}</td>
      <td class="pdf">PDF</td>
      <td class="audio">AUDIO</td>
      <td class="format">FORMAT</td>
      <td class="price">${{piece.price}}</td>
      <td><input class="qty" type="number" name="quantity" value="0"></td>
    </tr>
      {{#each part in piece.parts}}
      <tr>
        <td colspan="3">{{piece.name}}</td>
        <td class="partName">{{part.pname}}</td>
        <td class="partPrice">{{part.pprice}}</td>
        <td><input class="partQty" type="number" name="quantity" value="0"></td>
      </tr>
      {{/each}}
    {{/each}}
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! it makes a whole lot more sense now.