# ES6/React adding object to array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

Somewhere in the code lies a flaw if someone could spot it it I would appreciate help thank you.

**Step 1.** react form to add a record to the state containing two
 variables [**email** & **name**]

```
    export const AddForm = (props) => {

         const [ name, setName ] = useState('')
         const [ email, setEmail ] = useState('');

         return (
              <div>
                    Name:
                   <input type="text" 
                           id="name" 
                           onChange={ (event)=> { setName(event.target.value) }} /><br />
                   Email:
                   <input type="email" 
                           id="email" 
                           onChange={ (event)=> { setEmail(event.target.value) }}/><br />
                   <button type="button" 
                           onClick={ ()=> { props.doAdd(name,email) } } >Add</button>
              </div>
         )

    }
```

**Step 2.** The execution of the doAdd() function inside the main app.js

```
  const doAdd = (name,email) => {
    var newData = '{"name":'+name+',"email":'+email+'}';
    setAllVals([...allVals,newData]);

  }
```

after entering values my array of objects does not perform properly.  for example allVals[0].name = *blank* (it should be **`name1`**)

here is console.log
[image]

Comment: can you be more specific?

Comment: `var newData = '{"name":'+name+',"email":'+email+'}';` isnt adding a new object. Its a string, so `allVals` will not have any properties on it.

Comment: Even if it was an object, did you not mean `allVals[0].name`?

Comment: As Brian said. `newData` is a string, hence the double quotes around the entries in your array.

Comment: @evolutionxbox yes thank you I just corrected the post

Comment: Try `var newData = {name,email}`. This will give it property names of your variables and then assign them the values

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript object literal: what exactly is {a, b, c}?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34414766/javascript-object-literal-what-exactly-is-a-b-c)

Comment: @EmileBergeron it does thank you - I had my data types mixed up.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use this

```
const doAdd = (n,e) => {
    var newData = {name:n,email:e};
    setAllVals([...allVals,newData]);
  }
```

pass n to name-> `name:n` and e to email-> `email:e`. here your name and email is key of object and n,e are values.

It's similar to

```
var objExample = {
    key1: value1,
    key2: value2
};
```

you can check for better understanding [Objects](https://javascript.info/object)

Comment: @Nelles your welcome... if answer is helpful for you please accept/vote for this.

Comment: @Nelles Because the fact that `newData` is a string and not an object should have been easy to find with some basic debugging.

Comment: @Andreas truthfully you are correct - it was not throwing an error and I was trapped on it for a long time.  I apologise.

Comment: This isn't a very good answer... It gives no explanation as to why the error happens, or what your code does to address it. And it unnecessarily changes the parameter names of the OP's function to be completely meaningless single letters.