# Why when I copy the variable doesn't work

Tags: javascript

Why this code worked for me, i want to do a request

```
const ChangeSettings= (flag)=>{

    await client.put(`${MyEndpoint}/${car}`, {
      flag,
    })
```

but when i copy in a new var, dont work

```
const ChangeSettings = (flag)=>{

    let copyFlag=flag
        await client.put(`${MyEndpoint}/${car}`, {
          copyFlag,
        })
```

what is the wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript object literal: what exactly is {a, b, c}?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34414766/javascript-object-literal-what-exactly-is-a-b-c)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

flag is an object which has a key `flag` and you are passing an object `copyFlag` with a key `copyFlag`. Hence the issue

**Use this**

```js
const updateUserSettingsInfo = (flag)=>{

    let copyFlag=flag
        await client.put(`${MyEndpoint}/${car}`, {
          flag: copyFlag, //<---- change the key of an object
        })
```

side note - since you are awaiting in your function, make sure to use `async`

```js
const updateUserSettingsInfo = async (flag) => {
...
```