# Javascript - Math.random inside nested loop returns same sequence every time

Tags: javascript, for-loop, random, nested-loops

I'm trying to randomize values inside inside a nested loop:

```js
let bools = {
  first: true,
  second: true,
  third: true,
  fourth: true,
  fifth: true,
};

results = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  for (let k in bools) {
    bools[k] = Math.random() > 0.5;
    console.log(bools[k]);
  }
  results.push({ i, bools });
}
console.log(results);
```

The results are the same sequence for each iteration of i.  I was confused by this and tried a performance timestamp instead of a random number:

```
bools[k] = now() // from performance-now node package
```

and it returned the same precision timestamp sequence for each iteration also.  What this tells me is the inner loop is running only once.  Why not every iteration of the outer for loop?  How can I get around this?  Thx :)

Comment: You only manipulate a single object called `bools` and insert it several times in `result`.

Comment: I see that you have used `results.push({ i, bools });`. What are you expecting from this? I have no idea if that is actually something. Would something like `results.push({ i: bools });` work better? Or do the two do the same thing?

Comment: @Rojo it's still *the same object* inserted in several slots

Comment: @Rojo https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34414766/javascript-object-literal-what-exactly-is-a-b-c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to replace:

```
 results.push({ i, bools });
```

with:

```
    results.push({ i, bools: Object.assign({}, bools) });
```

You keep referencing the same object 'bools' and constantly overriding it, so in the end you'll see result of the last iteration in every elemen of the 'results' array.
On the other side 'Object.assign({}, bools) creates new object every time from the 'bools' reference.
Read about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)