# How can the index of an object within an array be preserved when modifying an object property while using the spread operator?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am having a React useState-Variable that stores an Array of Objects
which are of this Question type:

```
type Question = {
id: number,
text: string,
otherProps: string,
...... (and so on)
}
```

Example of my useState

```
const [questions, setQuestions] = React.useState<Question[]>([{id: 1, text: "hello?", otherProps: "Lorem Ipsum"}])
```

The order of these Question objects in the useState-Variable Array matters, so **my question is: How should the following function be changed so that the text of the Question is changed but the array index of the modified object is maintained/kept?**
I am aware that currently I am first deleting the object and then placing a newly created on at the end, but I can't figure out another way right now.

```
function setQuestionTextById(id:number, text:string) {
    if (!questions) return;
    const question:Question|undefined = questions.find(x => x.id === id);
    if (!question) return;
    const newQuestion: Question = {
        ...question,
        text,
    };
    const filteredQuestions = questions.filter(item => item.id !== id);
    setQuestions([...filteredQuestions, newQuestion]);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `map` on the array with a function that checks if the `id` is the one you want - if so it modifies it with the new `text`, otherwise leaves it as is.

This way, your whole function becomes:

```
function setQuestionTextById(id:number, text:string) {
    const updatedQuestions = questions.map(question => question.id === id ? { ...question, text } : question);
    setQuestions(updatedQuestions);
}
```

Which I find much more readable than the original, as well as preserving order as you say you need.

One further refinement would be to use the [functional update](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates) form of `setQuestions` so it doesn't depend on the previous value of `questions`, but I'll leave that up to you - it may not matter, depending on how this is being used in your component.

Comment: wouldn't it need to be `{...question, text: text}` ?

Comment: that's the same thing in longhand form. I just prefer typing less, along with most developers. See eg [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34414766/javascript-object-literal-what-exactly-is-a-b-c) for an explanation