# What does it mean when a Typescript object has key, but no value?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have seen typescript objects defined like this:

```
        const MyObj = {
          myVar1,
          name1: myVar2
        }
```

What is this object being defined here?

I understand that there is a key value pair here where `name1` is the key, and `myVar2` is the value. But what does it mean for there to be only a single value like `myVar1`?

(This is very hard to Google an answer for)

Comment: It is equivalent to `myVar1: myVar1`.

Comment: … whick links to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34414766/javascript-object-literal-what-exactly-is-a-b-c

Answer (score -1):

It's a shorthand declaration. There is some variable named `myVar1` and this code says that on the object `myObj`, there will be a key with the name `myVar1` with the value equalling the variable.

There are multiple shorthands for creating objects in TypeScript. Another is object deconstruction seen when you do this: `const obj1 = {name: 'John'}; const obj2 = {...obj1}`. This makes obj2 have all the same properties as obj1.