# Synchronous code in then handler of Promise

Tags: javascript, promise

I need to execute some synchronous code after an asynchrnous Promise is resolved. Currently my code looks like this:

```
console.log("Starting");

promiseFunc().
then(function() {
  console.log("PromiseFunc done. Doing Synchronous work...");
  synchronousFunc1();
  synchronousFunc2();
  console.log("Synchronous work done");
}).
catch(function(err) {
  console.log("Error:" + err);
}).
then(function() {
  console.log("Done")
});
```

Everything is working fine: The first `then` is executed after `promiseFunc` is resolved and the final `then` is executed last.
I think the spec expects me to return a new Promise or a value from the `then`, but there is nothing useful I can return.
Here are my questions:

1. Does this 'pattern' for executing synchronous code after a promise is resolved make sense? Is it okay to return undefined from the `then` block?
2. What happens if someone decides to implement `synchronousFunc1` with a promise? This will break the order of execution.
   I think such a breaking change shouldn't be made. Instead another `asynchronousFunc1` should be implemented. Am I right?
3. What about my `catch/then` implementation? The final `then` should be executed always. I think this will not work, if an exception is thrown in the `catch` handler. Are there alternatives? I know there is a `finally` handler in bluebird, but I want to use standard Promise features only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does this 'pattern' for executing synchronous code after a promise is resolved make sense?

Yes. That's what we all do.

> Is it okay to return `undefined` from the `then` block?

Not really, every work should have a result (otherwise it would be pointless) and you should `return` that. But if your function is only executing side effects, then returning `undefined` is the result, so it's okay.

> What happens if someone decides to implement `synchronousFunc1` with a promise? This will break the order of execution.

Yes, that's a breaking change.

> I think such a breaking change shouldn't be made. Instead another `asynchronousFunc1` should be implemented. Am I right?

How breaking changes are handled depends on the policy of the library and its contracts with callers. It might be a major version update, it might be a new function, it might be anything; it should be announced properly of course. You'll have to change your code anyway.

If the name of the function suggests that it's synchronous, it shouldn't return a promise; the name should be changed with the implementation in that case.

> What about my `catch/then` implementation? The final `then` should be executed always. I think this will not work, if an exception is thrown in the `catch` handler.

Correct. You'll have to make sure that the `catch` handler doesn't throw :-)

> Are there alternatives? I know there is a `finally` handler in bluebird, but I want to use standard Promise features only.

If you are using bluebird, you should use `finally`. It'll likely become standardised anyway, and many other libs support it as well. If not, you can always [shim it yourself](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32362233/1048572). Its implementation is superior to yours, especially about return values and handling things like cancellation appropriately.

Comment: Great answer. Thank you!