# Is there a way to return a promise to .catch and .then

Tags: javascript, node.js

Basically I want to run the same code regardless if the code throws an error or not. Now I'm doing this:

```
.then((resp) => {
    assert(false);
}, err => {
    assert.equal(2, err.error.errors.length);
    });
});
```

But I would like to do something like this:

```
.something((resp, err) => {
    assert.equal(400, resp.statusCode)
    assert.equal(2, err.error.errors.length);
}
```

Comment: Some promise libraries like bluebird implement a `.finally()`

Comment: @slebetman, cool, but it doesn't seem to have any variables?

Comment: Your `something` callback doesn't make sense. There's no way `resp` and `err` would ever be available at the same time - there's a good reason why `then` takes *two* callbacks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ES6 promise settled callback](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32362057/1048572)?

Answer (score 3):

#### You *can* do it...

...just use `catch` and return something from it, then use `then` on the promise `.catch` returns:

```
thePromise
    .catch(err => err)
    .then(resultOrError => {
        // Your code
    });
```

The argument your `then` callback receives (`resultOrError` in the above) will be the resolved value if the promise was resolved, or the rejected value (loosely, "error") if it was rejected. You can naturally do something more in `catch` if you want to differentiate them.

Example (run it a few times, you'll see it get resolved, and also rejected):

```js
let p = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    if (Math.random() < 0.5) {
      resolve("success");
    } else {
      reject("error");
    }
  }, 0);
});
p.catch(err => err).then(resultOrError => {
  console.log("Got this:", resultOrError);
});
```

#### ...but alternately

...you can just have a a common function both callbacks call, after using the resolved value or the rejected value:

```
function doSomethingNoMatterWhat() {
    // ...
}

thePromise
    .then(result => {
        // Presumably use `result`, then:
        doSomethingNoMatterWhat();
    })
    .catch(error => {
        // Presumably use `error`, then:
        doSomethingNoMatterWhat();
    });
```

Comment: How would I access err from inside .then?

Comment: @Himmators `val` will be the `err`. But I am still not sure what exactly you are trying to do