# Promises propagating intermediate objects (NodeJS + MongoDB)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, ecmascript-6, es6-promise

I'm trying to use MongoDB with Promises in Node 4.x

In this example I want to:

1. Connect to my mongodb
2. THEN delete everything with a given Key
3. THEN insert one record
4. THEN close the connection

luckily the mongodb client spits out promises when you don't give it a callback. Here's what I came up with.

```js
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const test = require('assert');

function insertDoc(doc, collName) {
  return MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/myDB')
    .then(db => {
      const col = db.collection(collName);
      return col.deleteMany({ 'Key': doc.key })
        .then(() => col.insertOne(doc))
        .then(result => test.equal(1, result.insertedCount))
        .then(() => db.close);
    });
}
```

The code seems to work but the nested `.then()` "feels" wrong. Any ideas how to do it so that the `db` object can be used when I'm ready to `.close()` it?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your code and nested `then`s (except that you should use `finally` not `then` for the `close` callback)

Comment: @Bergi There's no `.finally` in es6 promises is there?

Comment: @jib: [There's not](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32362233/1048572), but you still need its functionality for `close`

Comment: @Bergi `.then(() => db.close(), e => (db.close(), Promise.reject(e)))` or something like it, agree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to treat the promises more as values, then pull out the wrapped value when you need it. It has its own readability downsides though.

e.g.

```
function insertDoc(doc, collName) {
  const db = MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/myDB');
  const col = db.then(db => db.collection(collName));

  return col.deleteMany({ 'Key': doc.key })
    .then(() => col.insertOne(doc))
    .then(result => test.equal(1, result.insertedCount))
    // You've still got the 'db' promise here, so you can get its value
    // to close it.
    .then(() => db.then(db => db.close()));
}
```

Comment: On readability, I sometimes use this, but find calling it `haveDb` to be beneficial, to distinguish it from its value. e.g. `haveDb.then(db => {})`. As in "when I have db, then do this with it".

Comment: Nice. I like this slightly better than what I was doing

Answer (score 1):

As it stands you can use a variable in the outer scope to achieve this:

```
let db;

function insertDoc(doc, collName) {
  return MongoClient.connect(dsn)
    .then(connectedDb => {
      db = connectedDb;
      return col.deleteMany(doc)
    }) // now you can chain `.then` and still use `db`
}
```

There are a few possible alternatives such as passing `db` along, but this would seem weird to me. If you want to keep this flow but still take advantage of asynchronicity, you can use `async`/`await`. Right now you will need a transpiler such as babel and something like the regenerator-runtime to use it.

```
async function insertDoc(doc, collName) {
  const db = await MongoClient.connect(dsn);
  const col = db.collection(collName);
  await col.deleteMany({Key: doc.key});
  const result = await col.insertOne(doc);
  await test.equal(1, result.insertedCount) // is this asynchronous?
  return db.close();
}
```

You can also use [`co`](https://github.com/tj/co)/`yield` to avoid transpiling although it's a bit more verbose.

Comment: I sometimes do the first one, but it's not very clean scoping-wise. It can have side effects like `db` sticking around after it should have been garbage collected.

Answer (score 0):

I find what you have to be the most readable pattern of alternatives I've seen. I myself use indentation (nested `.then`'s) to access previous values (and that's the only time I do it!)

So many things end up affecting how the code looks and reads. Take your `col` temporary for example. If it weren't needed, your code might have looked like this:

```
var insertDoc = (doc, collName) => MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:x/DB')
  .then(db => db.collection(collName).deleteMany({ 'Key': doc.key })
    .then(() => db.collection(collName).insertOne(doc))
    .then(result => test.equal(1, result.insertedCount))
    .then(() => db.close))
  .then(() => doSomethingElse());
```

Note the extra `)` after `db.close)`. An editor that bracket-matches is helpful. :)

I'm not suggesting dropping `col` for the sake of code beauty. I'm only showing this because I think it highlights how indentation shows the scope of the `db` value well. It's when I saw code like this, that I started liking this pattern.

In real life code doesn't always collapse neatly, but I like a pattern where it does when it can.