# Babel-polyfill Promises and "finally" support

Tags: javascript, promise, babeljs

How to enable `finally` method support if i'm using `babel-polyfill` in my project build on `React-Redux` stack

Comment: What kind of promises are you using? ES2015 ("ES6") promises don't have `finally`, so there's nothing to "enable." If you're using some other kind with a `finally` feature that requires enabling, please say what they are.

Comment: Maybe completely other polyfill like `es6-shim`. Does it provide coverage for React ?

Comment: But `babel-polyfill` dosen't implement it. And i search a way to gracefully add this missing feature

Comment: @MisterEpic: You're talking about `finally` in regard to `try`/`catch`. The OP is talking about it as a method on promises (sometimes people add it, as `finally` or as `always`).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ES6 promise settled callback](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32362057/1048572)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ES6 standard does not support the `finally` phase of a promise, as T.J. Crowder mentioned in the comments to your question.  If you want that kind of support, you might look into promises from a library like [RSVP](https://github.com/tildeio/rsvp.js).

Answer (score 4):

Actually, now it has a [proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-promise-finally), and it's recently got into Stage-3, [WebKit already supports it](https://twitter.com/malyw/status/890944291467669504). Spec compliant [shim/polyfill libraries](https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=promise%20finally) are already available too. We can expect an update from the Promise polyfill library maintainers also.

Answer (score 1):

I believe, the [Babel-Polyfill](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/polyfill/) shim uses core-js under the hood, which does support Promise.finally: https://github.com/zloirock/core-js#commonjs

[image]