# How can I use 'finally' within a 'Promise' clause in NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, promise, try-catch-finally

I want something like this:

```
let promises = [];
for (let i = 0; i < some_length; i++) {
    let output = '';
    promises.push(some_func(i)
        .then((result) => {
            output = result;
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            output = error.message;
        })
        .finally(() => {
            console.log(output);
        })
    );
}
return Promise.all(promises);
```

But I get a runtime error `.then(...).catch(...).finally is not a function`.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: `finally` is not yet in the standard, and therefore not supported by Node. You can use [this polyfill](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32362233/1048572) though

Comment: @Bergi: OK, so in other words, switch to the (newer) `async`/`await` paradigm, which we are planning to do at some point anyway, but were hoping that there would be a similar mechanism in `Pomise` paradigm. Thank you!!!

Comment: @goodvibration `async`/`await` is still using the promise paradigm, it just has more syntactic sugar.

Comment: Btw, for the example in your question I would recommend to simplify to `some_func(i).catch(err => err.message).then(console.log)` (which is probably even better than any `finally`+`await`, as there you always need that `output` variable)

Answer (score 2):

Node 10 finally added support for it. Tested with node 10.7.0.

```
Promise.resolve().finally(() => {
    console.log("It finally works!")
})
```

> It finally works!

(Chrome and Firefox also support it btw.)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I Think your `some-func` function isn't return `Promise`, with returning `JavaScript` `Promise`es the `then`, `catch` and `finally` has meaning, so I think you must declare `some_func` function as a `new` instance of `Promise` object, see below code:

```
let promises = [];
for (let i = 0; i < some_length; i++) {
    let output = '';
    let some_func = (i) => {
       return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            setTimeout(resolve(`success: ${i}`), 100, 'foo');
       });
    }
    promises.push(some_func(i)
        .then((result) => {
            output = result;
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            output = error.message;
        })
        .finally(() => {
            console.log(output);
        })
    );
}
return Promise.all(promises);
```

Maybe this code have some other errors, I don't know because I do not test it, but undoubtedly your error is for just like I said in above sentences.