# What was the reasoning behind not special-casing a resolved value of undefined from Promise#finally?

Tags: javascript, promise, language-lawyer, specifications, finally

### Background

The TC39 [`proposal-promise-finally`](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-promise-finally), which is now part of the [ES2018 specification](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/index.html#sec-promise.prototype.finally), lists [the following key points](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-promise-finally#why-not-thenf-f) also [paraphrased on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/finally#Description) to describe exactly what the method does.

> `promise.finally(func)` is similar to `promise.then(func, func)`, but is different in a few critical ways:
>
> - When creating a function inline, you can pass it once, instead of being forced to either declare it twice, or create a variable for it
> - A `finally` callback will not receive any argument, since there's no reliable means of determining if the promise was fulfilled or rejected. This use case is for precisely when you *do not care* about the rejection reason, or the fulfillment value, and so there's no need to provide it.
> - Unlike `Promise.resolve(2).then(() => {}, () => {})` (which will be resolved with `undefined`), `Promise.resolve(2).finally(() => {})` will be resolved with `2`.
> - Similarly, unlike `Promise.reject(3).then(() => {}, () => {})` (which will be resolved with `undefined`), `Promise.reject(3).finally(() => {})` will be rejected with `3`.
>
> However, please note: a `throw` (or returning a rejected promise) in the `finally` callback will reject the new promise with that rejection reason.

In other words, a concise polyfill using a [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) implementation that conforms to the [Promises/A+ specification](https://promisesaplus.com/) is as follows (based on the answers by [@Bergi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32362233/1541563) and [@PatrickRoberts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53327815/1541563)).

```js
Promise.prototype.finally = {
  finally (fn) {
    const onFulfilled = () => this;
    const onFinally = () => Promise.resolve(fn()).then(onFulfilled);
    return this.then(onFinally, onFinally);
  }
}.finally;
```

If we contrast a promise chain using `Promise#then` and `Promise#finally` with an `async function` containing a `try...finally` block, we can determine some key differences, which are also mentioned but not elaborated [here](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-promise-finally#naming).

```js
const completions = {
  return (label) { return `return from ${label}`; },
  throw (label) { throw `throw from ${label}`; }
};

function promise (tryBlock, finallyBlock) {
  return Promise.resolve()
    .then(() => completions[tryBlock]('try'))
    .finally(() => completions[finallyBlock]('finally'));
}

async function async (tryBlock, finallyBlock) {
  try { return completions[tryBlock]('try'); }
  finally { return completions[finallyBlock]('finally'); }
}

async function test (tryBlock, finallyBlock) {
  const onSettled = fn => result => console.log(`${fn}() settled with '${result}'`);
  const promiseSettled = onSettled('promise');
  const asyncSettled = onSettled('async');
  console.log(`testing try ${tryBlock} finally ${finallyBlock}`);
  await promise(tryBlock, finallyBlock).then(promiseSettled, promiseSettled);
  await async(tryBlock, finallyBlock).then(asyncSettled, asyncSettled);
}

[['return', 'return'], ['return', 'throw'], ['throw', 'return'], ['throw', 'throw']]
  .reduce((p, args) => p.then(() => test(...args)), Promise.resolve());
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{max-height:100%!important}
```

This demonstrates that the semantics for the settled state of the resulting promise differ from the analog `try...finally` block.

### Question

What was the reason for not implementing `Promise#finally` such that a special case for a callback that resolved to `undefined` using [the promise resolution procedure](https://promisesaplus.com/#the-promise-resolution-procedure) was the only condition for which a resolved `finally()` re-adopted the state of the original promise?

Using the following polyfill, the behaviors would match more closely with the analog `try...finally` block, except for when the `finally` block contains an explicit `return;` or `return undefined;` statement.

```js
Promise.prototype.finally = {
  finally (fn) {
    const onFulfilled = value => value === undefined ? this : value;
    const onFinally = () => Promise.resolve(fn()).then(onFulfilled);
    return this.then(onFinally, onFinally);
  }
}.finally;
```

As a follow-up question, in case the consensus is that the current specification is more palatable than the suggestion above, are there any canonical usages of `Promise#finally` that would be more cumbersome to write if it used this instead?

Comment: I think it's a great question. Just... not for Stack Overflow (as it's a question that really only a small, very specific set of people can answer factually). Another Stack Exchange site might be more suitable, such as [Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Btw, using `async` as a function name is highly confusing, and invalid in strict mode.

Comment: @rossipedia what's funny is that Bergi was the exact person I was hoping to get an answer from, so I guess it worked out :)

Comment: @Bergi Using `async` as a function name is _not_ invalid in strict mode, otherwise strict mode would not be backwards compatible with ES2016 and earlier, where it was commonplace to use `async` as an identifier (e.g. `caolan/async`). I'll accept that it's confusing though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This demonstrates that the semantics for the settled state of the resulting promise differ from the analogue `try...finally` block.

Not really, you just used the "wrong" `try`/`finally` syntax in your comparison. Run it again with

```
async function async (tryBlock, finallyBlock) {
  try { return completions[tryBlock]('try'); }
  finally {        completions[finallyBlock]('finally'); }
//          ^^^^^^ no `return` here
}
```

and you will see that it is equivalent to `.finally()`.

> What was the reason for not implementing `Promise#finally` such that a special case for a callback that resolved to `undefined` using the promise resolution procedure was the only condition for which a resolved `finally()` re-adopted the state of the original promise?

The proposal gives the [following rationale](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-promise-finally#naming): "*`Promise#finally` will not be able to modify the return value […] - since there is no way to distinguish between a “normal completion” and an early `return undefined`, the parallel with syntactic finally must have a slight consistency gap.*"

To give an explicit example, with the `try`/`catch` syntax there is a semantic difference between

```
finally {
}
```

and

```
finally {
    return undefined;
}
```

but the promise method cannot be implemented to distinguish between

```
.finally(() => {
})
```

and

```
.finally(() => {
    return undefined;
})
```

And no, it simply made no sense to introduce any special casing around `undefined`. There's always a semantic gap, and fulfilling with a different value is not a common use case anyway. You rarely see any `return` statements in normal `finally` blocks either, most people would even consider them a code smell.

Comment: I think you were spot-on to point out that I should be removing the `return` statement in my analog `try...finally` block, and I somewhat agree that modifying the return value of a function in a `finally` block is code-smell. On the other hand, what irks me is that the specification essentially prevents an entire class of possible continuations, while the minor change in semantics I suggested only prevents the continuation of a single value `undefined`, in order to use it for differentiating between the intent of modifying the resolved value vs just following another asynchronous continuation.

Comment: To clarify what I'm saying, with my change, you have an equivalent for both `finally { return ...; }` and `finally { ...; }`, assuming you don't need an equivalent for `finally { return undefined; }`, whereas with the specification of `Promise#finally`, you only have an equivalent for `finally { ...; }`, and it makes it very cumbersome to create an equivalent for `finally { return ...; }`.

Comment: I guess not supporting *any* return values is more consistent than supporting some return values *except* for one. It would lead to weirder edge cases that a code author would need to account for. While the change in semantics might be minor, the standardised semantics are still (a bit) simpler than those you proposed.

Comment: Btw if you absolutely want to have a new return value, you can use `.catch(e => {}).then(() => …)`.

Comment: Your point about "weirder edge cases for code authors" seems a likely answer to why the semantics I suggested were not used in the specification. Thank you for being so responsive to my follow-up.