# Break out of Async Function Within a Catch Block

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, try-catch

I have the following function:

```
async myFunction() {
    await this.somePromiseFunction().then(
      () => alert('Promise Complete!'),
      () => {
        throw new Error('Error');
      }
    ).catch(() => {
      alert('End the Function Here');
      });

    alert('Do not get called if error caught above.');
    await this.anotherPromiseFunction().then(
      () => alert('Promise Complete!'),
      () => {
        throw new Error('Error');
      }
    ).catch(() => {
      alert('End the Function Here');
      });
}
```

I would like it such that when an error is caught in the promise return handler that it ends the asynchronous function as I do not want it to continue in that case.

Comment: Why don't you put the alert inside the try block.That way if an error occurs the alert won't execute

Comment: I have multiple promises in my real function, this would mean I would have nest each of them in the previous try block, I want them to stay separated.

Comment: Maybe post your full code so we can see if it can be refactored and if we can fix your problem

Comment: Added other promise function, essentially, I will have many of these in a row and would most definitely want to avoid nesting them within each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of mixing `await` with `.then()`, just `await` each asynchronous function call directly in a `try` block and deal with the error appropriately.

If the asynchronous function returns a rejected promise, `await` will cause the rejection to throw from the `try` block and be caught, skipping the rest of the control flow inside the `try`.

```js
const asyncFactory = label => async () => {
  await new Promise(resolve => { setTimeout(resolve, 1000); });

  if (Math.random() < 0.25) {
    throw new Error(`${label} Error`);
  }

  console.log(`${label} Complete!`);
};

const somePromiseFunction = asyncFactory('somePromiseFunction');
const anotherPromiseFunction = asyncFactory('anotherPromiseFunction');

async function myFunction() {
  try {
    console.log('Start myFunction here');
    await somePromiseFunction();
    await anotherPromiseFunction();
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('Error caught:', error.message);
  } finally {
    console.log('End myFunction here');
  }
}

myFunction();
```

You can actually achieve the equivalent without using `async` and `await`, and you don't need to nest your promises to do so:

```js
const asyncFactory = label => () => {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(resolve, 1000);
  }).then(() => {
    if (Math.random() < 0.25) {
      throw new Error(`${label} Error`);
    }

    console.log(`${label} Complete!`);
  });
};

const somePromiseFunction = asyncFactory('somePromiseFunction');
const anotherPromiseFunction = asyncFactory('anotherPromiseFunction');
const oneMorePromiseFunction = asyncFactory('oneMorePromiseFunction');

function myFunction() {
  console.log('Start myFunction here');

  return somePromiseFunction().then(() => {
    return anotherPromiseFunction();
  }).then(() => {
    return oneMorePromiseFunction();
  }).catch(error => {
    console.log('Error caught:', error.message);
  }).finally(() => {
    console.log('End myFunction here');
  });
}

myFunction();
```

Do note that [`Promise.prototype.finally()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/finally) is actually part of [ECMAScript 2018](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript#9th_Edition_-_ECMAScript_2018), so if the browser supports it natively, it will also already support `async` and `await`. However, it can be [polyfilled](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53327815/1541563) while `async` and `await` cannot.

Comment: Perfect! This is exactly what I needed in my case.