# Node: Is behavior well-defined for Promise.all with non-Promise values?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

The [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) for `Promise.all()` describe the argument as an array of Promises. Is behavior defined if some (or all) of the elements in the array are non-Promise values? For example, in Node 6.10.2:

```
Promise.all([1, 2, 3]).then(
  res => console.log(res)
);
```

Prints `[ 1, 2, 3 ]`, as expected. Is this behavior (where `Promise.all` resolves with the same values that it was called with) **guaranteed** in Node?

Comment: From my little bit of googling it looks like [`Promise.all` is defined in the ECMAScript standard](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-promise.all).

Comment: [Yup](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all#Using_Promise.all)

Comment: Thanks @zzzzBov and `aaaaaa` — happy to accept an answer if you want to post one :)

Comment: @zzzzBov - Can you tell in that spec 25.4.4.1 where the OP's question is actually answered?

Comment: @jfriend00, didn't have time to dig in and actually read the spec, just had an inkling of where the info might be.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Are there promise standards for extended functions like .all(), etc](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27283401/1048572)?

Comment: `Promise.all` never resolves with the same value that it was called with, it always creates a new array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Promise.all()` is specified in the ES6 specification.

It appears that [section 24.4.4.1.1 in that ES6 specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-promise.all) at step 6.i describes how each item in the iterable passed to `Promise.all()` is passed to a promise constructor (essentially calling `Promise.resolve(item)`) so that any non-promise gets wrapped in a promise that will resolve itself on the next tick.

You need to follow the overall context of how these steps work to fully understand, but the specific 6.i step is this:

> Let nextPromise be Invoke(constructor, "resolve", «‍nextValue»).

Where `constructor` (in this context) is `Promise` and `Invoke()` is calling the `resolve` method on it - so it's essentially doing:

```
let nextPromise = Promise.resolve(nextValue);
```

Which is how each item in the iterable is wrapped in a promise if it wasn't already a promise.

Then, later in step 6.r, it does this:

> Let result be Invoke(nextPromise, "then", «‍resolveElement, resultCapability.[[Reject]]»).

Which is where it calls `.then()` on `nextPromise` which will now work fine even if the item in the iterable was not originally a promise because it has been wrapped in a new promise.

And, in [24.4.4.5](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-promise.resolve) the description of `Promise.resolve(x)` is as follows:

> The resolve function returns either a new promise resolved with the passed argument, or the argument itself if the argument is a promise produced by this constructor.

So, you can see that the value is wrapped in a new promise if it is not already a promise.

---

> Is this behavior (where `Promise.all()` resolves with the same values that it was called with) guaranteed in Node?

Yes, if the values are not promises, then it will resolve with an array of the same values.  It will be a different array, but the same values in the new array.  If any of the values are promises, then obviously, the final array contains the resolved value of that promise.  This is guaranteed by the specification.

Comment: I noticed that in the spec as well — it seemed to be wrapping iterator values in a Promise, but I wasn't completely sure that's what it says the first time I read it. Thanks for clarifying!